# Getting the value of the MaxLength attribute of a column in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I want to have a max length property set in a text field in html.

I have the following code in my razor code:

```
<td>
        <label asp-for="AspNetUser.FirstName" ></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" asp-for="AspNetUser.FirstName" asp-maxlength />
    </td>
```

My definition for the FirstName is:

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I get the following output:

```
<td>
    <label for="AspNetUser_FirstName">First Name</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field First Name must be a string or array type with a maximum length of &#x27;50&#x27;." data-val-maxlength-max="50" id="AspNetUser_FirstName" name="AspNetUser.FirstName" value="Wallace" />
</td>
```

If I put a value in that exceeds 50 characters, there is an error about truncation, which I would expect.  However, I would expect that somewhere I would be able to get the max length property and then use it to make sure that the maximum length is used.  How do I get this attribute value?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and not allow entries longer than 50 characters:

```
<td>
    <label asp-for="AspNetUser.FirstName" ></label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" asp-for="AspNetUser.FirstName" maxlength="50" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically do not want to hardcode the values.

Comment: So where do you wan the value to be received from?

Comment: I'd like to read some attribute from the property, such as:
GetObject("AspNetUsers").GetProperties().Property["MaxLength"] or similar.  This is a fairly common problem that has been solved in the past.  In classic ADO, you used ADOX, in ADO.NET, there were mechanisms for it.  Heck, I did it once in classic EF.  I'm looking for something besides hardcoding.  Since, I'm in Sql Server in Azure, I assume I can just go read this from the db.  I was just hoping for something built in.  :-)